# Error on referencing Exceptionless NuGet package to Xamarin projects

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nuget-package, exceptionless

I have a problem on referencing my [Exceptionless](https://github.com/exceptionless/Exceptionless) package. Has anyone ever tried referencing Exceptionless to a Xamarin project? I am having errors when referencing it.

**Questions:**

1. What Exceptionless project type do I use? Is it Console and Service Applications?
2. What package do I reference? Exceptionless or Exceptionless.Portable?

**Error Message:**

`Could not install package 'System.Security.Principal.Windows 4.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.`

I have implemented several solutions and none worked for me right now. I tried referencing the package to a portable class library project and the same error occurs. Hope someone has tried this before and can help me with a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was answered by one of the Exceptionless members, [Blake Niemyjski](https://github.com/niemyjski). Thanks!

**Question Answers:**

> 1. You'd need to install the Exceptionless package (Console and Service Applications).
> 2. Just the latest Exceptionless package.

**Referencing Error Solution:**

> I'm on version 6.1.0 but the way I installed it to was the portable project they generate and I changed the profile to:
>
> [image: Screenshot]
>
> Then I was able to reference exceptionless. I know they added support for .net standard but I've yet to get that to work in any of my samples. Can you please try this and let me know.

Full issue link [here](https://github.com/exceptionless/Exceptionless.Net/issues/121).

Comment: Thanks for posting this!

Comment: Thanks for the answer as well Blake.

Comment: No problem! Just a heads up, we have a branch with more changes that will really help out xamarin customers!